# FireFox this Function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, this

Why does Firefox not handle this.  This code works in IE.

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META NAME="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0">
</HEAD>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function drvFunc(elem)
{
    var e = elem.name;
    var d = "document."
    var f = "frm";
    var str = d+"."+f+"."+e+".value;";
    alert(eval(str));
}
</script>
<BODY>
<form name=frm method=post>
<input type=button name=myButton id=myButton value='MyButton' onclick='drvFunc(this)'>
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: NO GUYS, it's a bug in Stackoverflow's renderer.

Comment: I've fixed the question by indenting properly.  Please don't down-vote this guy just for that!

Comment: I seen that, what happened exactly?

Answer (score 13):

```
function drvFunc(elem) {
  alert(elem.value);
}
```

You don't need evil eval() for this function ...

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you have two periods being concatenated:

1. `var d = "document."`
2. `var str = d+"."+f...`

Your resulting string becomes: `"document..frm.myButton.value;"`

Remove one of the periods and it will work.

Comment: Or even better, use:
alert(document.frm[elem.name].value);
And get rid of everything else in the function;.

Comment: I agree... but this appears to be a learning exercise for the OP so I did not suggest (better) alternatives. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var d = "document."
```

to

```
var d = "document"
```

You are running eval with "document..frm"

Answer (score 1):

I'm the original author of this code thread.  I'm not sure I stated the problem correctly.

```
function drvFunc(elem)
{
    **var e = elem.name;** <-- in firefox, this fails.  e is not initialized!! 
    var d = "document."
...
}
```

On a form I might write some code like this and it works fine in IE...

```
<input type=button name=1stButton id=1stButton onclick='drvFunc(this)'>
<input type=button name=2ndButton id=2ndButton onclick='drvFunc(this)'>
```

...
then drvFunc could do this

```
function drvFunc(elem)
{

}
```

Comment: and put script in some more appropriate place, it cannot be a child of a document

Comment: To the original author: prefix all code with 4 spaces (mark the code and then click on the 0101 button) and it will be displayed correctly. If you look below your edit window you have a preview of how it will look. I edited this post for you.

Answer (score 1):

you could also go:

```
<input type='button' name='2ndButton' id='2ndButton' onclick='drvFunc(this.id)'> 

function drvFunc(elemid){ 
   alert(document.getElementById(elemid).value); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes (single or double) around the attributes on your `<input>` tag.

Firefox is probably handling unquoted attibutes differently to IE: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/qattr.html

You also need to remove the extra dot in `"document."` as others have said, and should probably refactor the `drvFunc` to remove `eval` as well.

The following works perfectly for me under Firefox 3:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META NAME="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0">
<script type='text/javascript'>
function drvFunc(elem)
{
    alert(elem.value);
}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form name="frm" method="post">
<input type="button" name="myButton" id="myButton" value="MyButton" onclick="drvFunc(this)">
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```